# Sum of the odd digits and even digits from the input and compare them. If both are equal print stat1 else stat2

Tags: c

This is the code, this code is not working. For loop needs to be used for this program. I need help to make this work. 
Program prints same statement for different numbers. Kindly debug this and help me to understand the concept.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,sum=0,sum1=0,rem;
    printf("enter values\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=n;i<=n;)
    {
        rem=n%10;
        if(rem%2 == 0)
        {
            sum=sum+rem;
        }
        else
        {
            sum1=sum1+rem;
        }
    n=n/10;
    }

if(sum==sum1)
    printf("I will win the Card Game");
else
    printf("I will not win the Card Game");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to test the return value from scanf(). Any program not doing so has a bug.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,sum=0,sum1=0,rem;

    printf("enter values\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 0; i < n;)
    {
        rem=n%10;
        if(rem%2 == 0)
        {
            sum=sum+rem;
        }
        else
        {
            sum1=sum1+rem;
        }
        n=n/10;
    }

    if(sum==sum1)
        printf("I will win the Card Game\n");
    else
        printf("I will not win the Card Game\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: There is no difference between 'for' and 'while' except the syntax. In this example you are using the 'for' loop without the full syntax, and it is working exactly like 'while' loop syntax. You can use 'for' loop with full syntax and then there will be a reason for using 'for' loop.

Comment: yes! It worked.could you please explain me what have u done?

Comment: Its the exact same as a while-loop. This basically is like writing `i = 0;` and `while(n > i(0) )`

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the length of user's number, and you will know how much numbers you got with this loop:

```
temp = n;
length = 0;
while (temp > 0) {
    length++;
    temp /= 10;
}
```

Then insert this code before your main loop, and in your main 'for' loop head you can use full 'for' syntax:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Put all together:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, sum = 0, sum1 = 0, rem, length, temp;

    printf("enter values\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    temp = n; // Temp variable to calculate digits' count
    length = 0; // Digits' counter
    while (temp > 0) { // Loop to calculate digits' count
        length++; // increase counter
        temp /= 10; // remove the unity digit, untill the number equal to 0.
    }

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) // go through all digits
    {
        rem = n % 10;
        if(rem % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + rem;
        }
        else
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + rem;
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }

    if(sum == sum1)
        printf("I will win the Card Game, sum: %d", sum);
    else
        printf("I will not win the Card Game, sum: %d, sum1: %d", sum, sum1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. could u please explain me what changes you have made?

Comment: @ElKhan I have inserted some comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use Array to get multiple values and compare them like below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,*arr,i,sum=0,sum1=0;

    printf("how many numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&n); 

    printf("enter values");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);    
       }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
       if(arr[i]%2 == 0)
          sum=sum+1;
      else
          sum1=sum1+1;

      }

if(sum==sum1)
    printf("I will win the Card Game");
else
    printf("I will not win the Card Game");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP wanted to take the digits of a single number, not an array of numbers.

Comment: Just do not forget to warn the user about the 10 numbers limitation.